# gSOAP server with multiple wsdl from ONVIF specifications

Tags: c++, web-services, wsdl, gsoap, onvif

I'm trying to create a web service in C++ using gSOAP.
I generated a couple of headers from ONVIF wsdl:

```
wsdl2h -x -o dm.h http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl -tC:\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\typemap.dat
wsdl2h -x -o an.h http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/analytics/wsdl/analytics.wsdl -tC:\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\typemap.dat
```

After that I compiled the headers generating C++ service proxies and objects:

```
soapcpp2.exe -j -S dm.h -IC:\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\import;C:\gsoap-2.8\gsoap -x -qDm
soapcpp2.exe -j -S an.h -IC:\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\import;C:\gsoap-2.8\gsoap -x -qAn
```

in order to obtain an application similar to the one described by gSOAP documentation: http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc7.2.8

Compiling in Visual Studio, i get the following errors:

```
error C3861: 'soap_in_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Fault': identifier not found
error C3861: 'soap_in_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Header': identifier not found
error C3861: 'soap_out_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Fault': identifier not found
error C3861: 'soap_out_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Header': identifier not found
```

I tried to follow what the documentation says (http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.35) about the serializers not being compiled at all because of the definition WITH_NOGLOBAL and compiled an empty env.h file, but that didn't solve the problem.

I searched the web but I can't find any solution. The problem seems related not to the Header and Fault themselves but the the pointers. Right?
What should I do?

Comment: Hi, did you solve your problem? 

I have same problem.

Comment: I ended up building a single header file from different wsdls:


`wsdl2h.exe -x -o onvif.h http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/analytics/wsdl/analytics.wsdl http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl -tC:\gsoap-2.8.22\gsoap\typemap.dat`


Then I compiled it:

`soapcpp2.exe -j -S onvif.h -IC:\gsoap-2.8.22\gsoap\import;C:\gsoap-2.8.22\gsoap -x -2`

I didn't find another way. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution.

1. Run `wsdl2h -x -Nan -o an.h http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/analytics/wsdl/analytics.wsdl`. Note that I'm using option `-Nan` here to let soapcpp2 generate two service/proxy classes for the two services defined by the two bindings in this WSDL. Otherwise you get one service/proxy class that combines the two together in one class, which is not elegant (but works either way).
2. Run `wsdl2h -x -o dm.h http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver20/analytics/wsdl/analytics.wsdl`
3. Create a new file `env.h`
4. Edit `env.h` and add `#import "xop.h"` and `#import "wsa5.h"`. Basically, you want all plugin-based headers to be imported here, since the plugins must work with global (non-C++-namespaced) structures. Also, the `env.h` file can be customized by adding a `struct SOAP_ENV__Header` and/or a `struct SOAP_ENV__Detail` structure. This is needed to exchange SOAP Headers and specific SOAP Fault details. In this case that won't be needed, since `#import "wsa5.h"` defines our SOAP Headers already for WS-Addressing.
5. Run `soapcpp2 -penv env.h` to generate the global SOAP Header and SOAP Fault serialization code (`envStub.h`, `envH.h` and `envC.cpp`).
6. Edit `an.h` and add the following definitions for SOAP Header and Faults

`an.h:`

```
struct SOAP_ENV__Header_
{
  // place SOAP Header elements here, if any
};
struct SOAP_ENV__Fault_
{
  char *faultcode;
  char *faultstring;
  char *faultactor;
  struct SOAP_ENV__Detail_ *detail;
  struct SOAP_ENV__Code_ *SOAP_ENV__Code;
  struct SOAP_ENV__Reason_ *SOAP_ENV__Reason;
  char *SOAP_ENV__Node;
  char *SOAP_ENV__Role;
  struct SOAP_ENV__Detail_ *SOAP_ENV__Detail;
};
struct SOAP_ENV__Detail_
{
  char *__any;
  int __type;
  void *fault;
};
struct SOAP_ENV__Code_
{
  char *SOAP_ENV__Value;
  struct SOAP_ENV__Code_ *SOAP_ENV__Subcode_;
};
struct SOAP_ENV__Reason_
{
  char *SOAP_ENV__Text;
};
```

7. In `an.h` change the line `struct SOAP_ENV__Envelope { struct SOAP_ENV__Header_ *SOAP_ENV__Header; _XML SOAP_ENV__Body; };` by using `struct SOAP_ENV__Header_` instead of `struct SOAP_ENV__Header`.
8. In `an.h` change line `struct SOAP_ENV__Fault_* Fault` by using `struct SOAP_ENV__Fault_` instead of `struct SOAP_ENV__Fault`.
9. Repeat the steps 6-8 for `dm.h`.
10. Now you can use C++ namespaces, so run `soapcpp2 -j -x -qAn -I $GSOAPPATH/gsoap/import -I $GSOAPPATH/gsoap an.h` to generate C++ service and proxy classes in the `An` namespace (with option `-qAn`).
11. Run `soapcpp2 -j -S -x -qDm -I $GSOAPPATH/gsoap/import -I $GSOAPPATH/gsoap dm.h`.
12. Since we're using the `duration` plugin (this custom serializer is optional, edit `typemap.dat` to remove it if desired and then rerun wsdl2h), copy `$GSOAPPATH/custom/duration.c` to local `duration.cpp` (note the .cpp extension, since MSVC++ does not like mixing .c with .cpp sources).
13. Edit `duration.cpp` and change `#include "soapH.h"` to `#include "anH.h"`.
14. Then compile the whole thing with your code, e.g. client-side `c++ yourclientapp.cpp DmC.cpp AnC.cpp envC.cpp DmDeviceBindingProxy.cpp AnRuleEngineBindingProxy.cpp AnAnalyticsEngineBindingProxy.cpp stdsoap2.cpp dom.cpp duration.cpp` or server-side `c++ yourserviceapp.cpp DmC.cpp AnC.cpp envC.cpp DmDeviceBindingService.cpp AnRuleEngineBindingService.cpp AnAnalyticsEngineBindingService.cpp stdsoap2.cpp dom.cpp duration.cpp`.
15. If you're using the WS-Addressing plugin, also compile `$GSOAPPATH/gsoap/plugin/wsaapi.c` with your code (but rename `wsaapi.c` to `wsaapi.cpp` since MSVC++ does not like mixing .c with .cpp sources).

**EDIT**

You can skip steps 6-8 if you change `typemap.dat` as follows, then rerun wsdl2h with the modified `typemap.dat`:

```
SOAP_ENV__Envelope  = struct SOAP_ENV__Envelope { struct SOAP_ENV__Header_ *SOAP_ENV__Header; _XML SOAP_ENV__Body; }; | struct SOAP_ENV__Envelope
SOAP_ENV__Header    = struct SOAP_ENV__Header_ { /* place SOAP Header elements here, if any */ }; | struct SOAP_ENV__Header_
SOAP_ENV__Fault     = \
struct SOAP_ENV__Fault_\
{\
  char *faultcode;\
  char *faultstring;\
  char *faultactor;\
  struct SOAP_ENV__Detail_ *detail;\
  struct SOAP_ENV__Code_ *SOAP_ENV__Code;\
  struct SOAP_ENV__Reason_ *SOAP_ENV__Reason;\
  char *SOAP_ENV__Node;\
  char *SOAP_ENV__Role;\
  struct SOAP_ENV__Detail_ *SOAP_ENV__Detail;\
};\
struct SOAP_ENV__Detail_\
{\
  char *__any;\
  int __type;\
  void *fault;\
};\
struct SOAP_ENV__Code_\
{\
  char *SOAP_ENV__Value;\
  struct SOAP_ENV__Code_ *SOAP_ENV__Subcode_;\
};\
struct SOAP_ENV__Reason_\
{\
  char *SOAP_ENV__Text;\
};\
| struct SOAP_ENV__Fault_
```

Comment: step 8. is redundant if you use '-O4' optimization switch with wsdl2h

Answer (score 0):

The code generated using the `-q` option seems to have a namespace problem with `soap_in_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Fault` and `soap_in_PointerToSOAP_ENV__Header`. The same problem occurs also with only 1 wsdl.

An other approach is to use the `-p` option like this :

```
soapcpp2.exe -j -S dm.h -IC:\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\import;C:\gsoap-2.8\gsoap -x -pDm
soapcpp2.exe -j -S an.h -IC:\gsoap-2.8\gsoap\import;C:\gsoap-2.8\gsoap -x -pAn
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue and almost lost my mind trying to find the solution. I noticed that a directive using `#ifndef WITH_NOIDREF` encapsulates some of `soap_(out|in)_PointerToSOAP_ENV__(Fault|Header)` indentifiers. Then when compile with the `WITH_NOIDREF` defined the erros messages decreases a little. So I manually encapsulates all the `soap_(out|in)_PointerToSOAP_ENV__(Fault|Header)` identifiers and it worked!

Example:

```
#ifndef WITH_NOIDREF
/// The soap_(out|in)_PointerToSOAP_ENV__(Fault|Header) indentifiers
// ...

#endif //WITH_NOIDREF
```

I'm afraid you are using windows, but I made some scripts to automate the whole process in:

https://github.com/yudi-matsuzake/onvif-mkmakefile